# Compute a smooth model assuming it exists

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, computability-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective geometrically connected variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let's say you know for a fact that $X$ has good reduction at $p$. Is there an algorithm that computes a smooth projective model $\mathcal{X}\to \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$?

Comment: This does not contradict anything in your post, but it is worth observing: there are examples with more than one (non-isomorphic) smooth projective model.  My favorite examples come from the two different types of punctual Hilbert schemes of a smooth Deligne-Mumford stack that is a specialization of a K3 surface.  I believe that there are also examples with countably many non-isomorphic smooth projective models.